# Referencing a private vector from another cpp file

Tags: c++, vector, reference

Ok so I am getting a "nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object" error when I attempt to pass a vector that is private(not changeable code inherited) from another cpp file. Now in order to make it accessible I made a return function that was basically supposed to return the one instance of the vector that is created. However I am getting the above error and I do not fully understand why as I thought I was returning a specific instance of the vector. see code below.

```
//-------------------------------------controller.h------------------------------

class Controller
{

public:
  controller();
  ~controller();

private:
  //some variables etc..
  std::vector<GroupAssignmentManager*> mAssignmentManagers; //vector declaration

public: 
  std::vector<GroupAssignmentManager*> getAssignmentManagersVec(); //funct decl
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------controller.cpp---------------------------------------

std::vector< AnalogGroupAssignmentManager* > Controller::getAssignmentManagersVec()
  {
      return mAssignmentManagers;  //function definition
  }

//--------------------------another cpp file----------------------------

#include "controller.h"


void updateDate()
{

//create a reference and set it equal to the real vector
std::vector<AnalogGroupAssignmentManager*>& mAssignmnetManagers = Controller::getAssignmentManagersVec();  // right side of the = causes the above error


}
```

Comment: You’ve forgot to close your class with };

Comment: You need `};` at the end of your class. Also you want to return the member by reference `std::vector<GroupAssignmentManager*> getAssignmentManagersVec();` -> `std::vector<GroupAssignmentManager*>& getAssignmentManagersVec();`

Comment: More important, you have declared a class, but not any instance of it, so you can’t call methods

Comment: If you're going to expose the private innards of Controller with a getter mutable reference, just make the member variable public.  You've already relinquished precondition requires, postcondition ensures, and class invariants; so the responsibility of class coherence for Controller is now distributed throughout the code.  Encapsulation has been stoutly thwarted.